# SQL developer configuration in MAC to point locally insatlled oracle

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer 18.0 and also using oracle docker image in the MAC OS. Now the requirement is we need to change the connection from TCP to TCPS connection which means we need to make changes in the TNSnames.ora file and accordingly need to change the listeners.ora file but we do not have oracle installed in my system we did not find those files hence I need to install oracle client in my system and point the SQL developer to it.

How can I achieve it, can you publish the links to install oracle `12c 12.1.0` in MAC and also the path of TNSnames.ora & listeners.ora. and also let me know which file to be browsed in the SQL developer preferences to point the tool to installed oracle. And after this does the docker is needed ? or do you have a solution to change it in the docker itself if so then let me know the exact steps.

Using below i am trying to connect from SQL developer to DB which is successful through TCP, i need to achieve this using TCPS which is currently failing

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB.localdomain)))

Comment: If you are using the thin driver in JDBC, you don't need a tnsnames.ora and SQL Developer (or actually the JDBC driver) will not use it.

Comment: My requirement is to connect through TCPS connection instead of TCP. I am trying to connect the DB as mentioned below.When i use TCP its working fine but its failing when i use TCPS. How can we achieve this.                                              jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB.localdomain)))